# Focal points to geodesic submanifolds defined by tangent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The following definitions are from *Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry* by Cheeger & Ebin.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. The geodesic submanifold defined by a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ is $\exp_p(B)$ where $B\ni0$ is a small ball in $\operatorname{span}(v)^\perp\subset T_pM$, so small that $\exp_p|_B$ is an embedding. Let $\gamma(t):=\exp_p(tv)$. We consider points focal to the geodesic submanifold defined by $v$ along the geodesic $\gamma$.

In the book there is a Rauch II, i.e., second Rauch comparison, which requires the geodesic to have no focal points in the above sense.

> **Question.** Let $c:[0,\ell]\to M$ be a geodesic and $E$ a parallel field along $c$ orthogonal to $c'$. Does there exist an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $t\in[0,\ell]$, the there are no points on the geodesic $$\gamma_t:[0,\varepsilon]\to M,s\mapsto\exp_{c(t)}(sE(t))$$ that is focal to the geodesic submanifold defined by $E(t)$ along $\gamma_t$?

This seems to be implicitly assumed in the proof of a lemma for the Cheeger–Gromoll soul theorem. However, I don't see why this is true. The existence of such a focal point is equivalent to having a critical point of some restriction of $\exp$, but for each $t$ the restrictions are different and don't seem to be related. So I don't know how to make the $\varepsilon$ uniform with respect to $t$.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Edit: It seems that the notion of focal points is not so well-known. Here it is in the sense as in, e.g., *Morse Theory* by Milnor. Let $N$ be a submanifold, $\gamma$ a unit-speed geodesic with $\gamma(0)\in N$, $\gamma'(0)\perp T_{\gamma(0)}N$. Let $T^\perp N\subset TM$ be the normal bundle of $N$. A point $\gamma(a)$ is said to be *focal* to $N$ along $\gamma$ if $\exp_p|_{T^\perp N}:T^\perp N\to M$ is singular at $a\gamma'(0)$ (note that $\exp(a\gamma'(0))=\gamma(a)$). In particular, when $N$ is a single point this reduces to the usual notion of conjugate points along a geodesic.

Comment: You haven't quoted the definition of when a point is focal but isn't the fact that the injectivity radius of a smooth compact manifold is strictly greater than zero sufficient for this?

Comment: @quarague Sorry, I thought it was well-known. I did however recall what it means. It means that the restriction of $\exp$ to the normal bundle of the geodesic submanifold is singular there. This is different from the injectivity radius, which concerns the restriction of $\exp$ to tangent spaces. You see, $\exp_p$ is defined on the $2n$-dimensional tangent bundle, and we are restricting to different $n$-dimensional submanifolds here. That's the difference between conjugate points and focal points.

Comment: Petersen, p.102: "A focal point occurs when integral curves for $\nabla r$ meet at a point". I don't understand your definition, but with Petersen's we have your claim because of what @quarague said.

Comment: @Mathy I just added the precise definition of focal points. Indeed conjugate points are special cases of focal points, so Petersen is not distinguishing between them.

Comment: Petersen says that there are metrics where there are conjugate points that are not focal points and yes, he distinguishes them (see p.102). Anyway, what am I not seeing here? If $p$ and $q = \exp(t\cdot v)$ are not conjugated, then $(dexp_p)_{t\cdot v}$ is an isomorphism and hence non-singular also on $T^{\bot}N \subset TM$.

Comment: @Mathy $T^\perp N$ is _not_ a submanifold of $T_pM$. $T^\perp N$ and $T_pM$ are two $n$-dimensional submanifolds of $TM$ which do not contain each other. For example, it could be the case that $\exp_p$ is singular but $\exp|_{T^\perp N}$ is singular along directions normal to the fibers of $TM$.

Comment: Okay, but also the normal exponential map satisfies that what @quarague said. But maybe that's not I enough; I should really think your whole question through before making more (useless) comments.